# Do I need to set a specific IP address to my computer to access the router configuration page?

Tags: networking, router, lan, ipv4

I'm from Colombia, my internet service provider is UNE and my router model is Huawei HG531 v1. Since before yesterday I've been trying to access my router configuration page to set some custom settings from there because of problems with WIFI connection on several devices. But cannot access the page yet.

The gateway or "Puerta de enlace predeterminada" is 192.168.1.254.

When I try to navigate to that address on my web browser (on linux and windows) the server "takes too long to response" but if I perform a ping all petitions are received.

So I have a couple of questions about this:

- Do I need to set a specific IP address to my computer to access the router configuration page or it should work even with the default IP address provided by the DHCP? If so:
- How can I found that IP address?

I don't know so much about networking so I would appreciate any information about how to achieve this goal. Thanks.

Comment: What's the output of `ipconfig /all` or `ifconfig` (depending on the OS you're using right now)?

Answer (score 0):

As per this [manual](http://setuprouter.com/router/huawei/hg531v1/manual-1943.pdf), try setting your adapter to automatically obtain an IP address and then navigate to 192.168.1.1.

Comment: I already read that manual but the configuration of my router seems to be quite different. The manual say that `192.168.1.1` should be the gateway but this one is `192.168.1.254` and I tried to navigate to that address from different devices with different operating systems, with static and dynamic IP address. But not success. So I've read somewhere that I must set `192.168.1.184` as the static IP of the computer I will access from. This configuration works with my neighbor router but that is not my case.

Answer (score 0):

UNE has installed a custom firmware in the router. Because of that you can't access the config page.
If you need to change something in the router you'll have to call the UNE customer service.